# making web site responsive via @media queries

Tags: responsive-design, media-queries

Currently I use my @media queries to change font-size based on min-width and max-width.

Should I change over to device-width in my @media selectors?

I do use this beauty ...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Because of the enormous amount of different screen sizes from tablets to HD screens used in TV studios, the amount of @media selectors gets super large.

I moan, considering phones, tablets, laptops, desktops, home TV screens, TV station screens ... not to mention portrait and landscape orientations.

Zooming on the Browser (CMD +-) does it automatically without my entering gobs of specific @media selectors.

PLEASE ... is there a shorter way?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use an already built responsive front-end framework like Bootstrap? You're not wrong that media queries are an absolute pain. You'll be chasing strange bugs forever if you're trying to homebrew a full responsive framework.

Comment: There are many fontend frameworks available to help you create responsive website with ease. You can find some of them here [link](https://www.agriya.com/blog/15-alternatives-bootstrap-foundation-skeleton/) . Learn about Chrome Developer Tools for debugging your design. You will not have to use ( CMD +/- ) and other ancient ways of developing a website.

Comment: Does Bootstrap automatically add all the correct media selectors?  If so, do I still need to add my rules like font-size: 110%

Comment: I want to avoid putting incorrect rules like font-size: 100%; where the correct nbr is 105%

Comment: I've had an hour looking at all the docs, so it's hardly anything to sneeze at. I did learn about the 4 break-points that Bootstrap recommends as you go from hand-held to TV station size. That is clearly beneficial and am very grateful for that knowledge. What I've concluded(?), however, is that the answer to my question above "Does Bootstrap automatically add ..." is "No". Assuming that is accurate, I guess I am still looking for an answer to my topmost question "Should I change over to device-width in my @media selectors?".

Comment: I believe rather than writing device specific `media-queries`, you should make it more generic like one media-query between screen width of 320px to 600px, another one from 600px to 900px, 900 to 1200, 1200 to 1600 and 1600+. This is really useful in reducing the number of  @media selectors. Hope this helps.